# Spring security session management and Spring MVC view resolver error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, session, spring-security

I am working on a Spring MVC web application. Last week I started adding Sping Secuirty to my project. The problem I am facing concerns session management.
Here is http part of my spring-security.xml

```
    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/css" filters="none"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/js" filters="none"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout" filters="none"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/loginfailed" filters="none"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" filters="none"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/hello"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
        <session-management invalid-session-url="/login.jsp?error=sessionExpired" session-authentication-error-url="/login.jsp?error=alreadyLogin">
           <concurrency-control max-sessions="1"  expired-url="/login.jsp?error=sessionExpiredDuplicateLogin" error-if-maximum-exceeded="false"/>
        </session-management>
    </http>
```

Login/logout works fine, but when I try to invalidate user session by trying to login from different browser invalid-session-url="/login.jsp?error=sessionExpired" fails. Browser get redirected, because I see that GET request to login.jsp?error=sessionExpired is being sent. However, web page shows error saying that resource is not available. I suspect that it has something to do with

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass">
    <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView</value>
  </property>
  <property name="prefix">
    <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
  </property>
  <property name="suffix">
    <value>.jsp</value>
  </property>
</bean>
```

in my dispatcher-servlet.xml. However, I don't know exactly how to fix this issue. login.jsp is located in WEB-INF/pages/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me Spring MVC DispatcherServlet couldn't find a mapping for /login.jsp because [it's not set as a view that accessible without controller](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-view-controller). I'm also assuming you had /login mapped to login.jsp (you did not provide enough info to confirm this), but if this is the case, just use `expired-url="/login?error=sessionExpiredDuplicateLogin`

Comment: thanks man! Works fine! Btw, I am kind of lost trying to understand difference between invalid-session-url, session-authentication-error-url,expired-url. I know there is documentation, but still maybe you could point me to a resource that would provide more detailed information.

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-session-management

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting to the jsp not the mapped url.

session management tag should be :

```
<session-management invalid-session-url="/login?error=sessionExpired" session-authentication-error-url="/login?error=alreadyLogin">
       <concurrency-control max-sessions="1"  expired-url="/login?error=sessionExpiredDuplicateLogin" error-if-maximum-exceeded="false"/>
</session-management>
```